# Which algorithm given this plot?

Tags: r, prediction

I computed a feature `x` that I use to predict `y` which is a **probability** of being a certain class.

**Raw data in R format for (x,y) is pasted here:** 
http://tny.cz/a97b3fd0
(500 samples)

plot(x,y) looks like this:

[image]

It seems similar to a [previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83554/linear-regression-not-fitting-well) I asked, so I am tempted to try [this advice](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/83613/21720), which I understand is the "Least Squared Fit"on log(y) (because y is a probability).

Am I correct?

(My objective is to minimize the MSE.)

Comment: Yes, clearly similar.  In fact, what's different?  Seems like the exact same story, at first glance.  (And it's not log(y), it's the log odds.)

Comment: @Aaron x is different. Thanks for pointing out about the log odds.

Comment: Huh? x is different how? Tell us the story of the data, and how the story is different.