# Appropriate to use logarithmic transformation?

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, python, logarithm

I'm a beginner experimenting with machine learning and regression.

I have a dataset that looks like the following, where cost is the target (dependent) variable.

[image: Original scatter matrix]

Since the relationships seem skewed and exponential, is it appropriate to take the log of all of them before applying linear regression, like the following figure?

[image: Scatter matrix of the log of variables]

Furthermore, only one of the variables, dose, has zero values, is it appropriate to add 1 only to that variable before I take the log or should 1 be added to all of them?

Is there anything else I should check or beware of before applying a logrithmic transformation?

Is there anything else in the shape of the data that is strange that I should investigate?

Comment: You ask a lot of (good) questions here, all of which I believe are answered in other posts on this site (now numbering into the thousands).  Please conduct a [search](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=+log+transformation).  The evident visual fact that the transformations have created a scatterplot matrix all of whose cells exhibit classic elliptical clouds, or nearly so, and have nearly symmetric marginal distributions, answers the question about whether those transformations are advisable.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know the term "elliptical cloud" before, it's a great search term that found other questions that didn't pop up before. However, I haven't yet found any questions that transformed into an elliptical cloud. Only found those who started with one, such as [this one](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/83554/linear-regression-not-fitting-well/83613#83613) and [this one](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/225882/what-does-this-plot-tell-me-about-my-linear-model/226054#226054.)  Which makes me think that it's an acceptable starting place?

Comment: Often, to sound less technical, people refer to these point clouds as having a shape of a "football" or "cigar."  Thus, "cloud" or "point cloud" might make better search terms than "elliptical cloud".